# Product review form not displaying on product view pages

Tags: magento-1.9, xml

I have tried [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/35170/37202) and many other solutions to display review form on product view page but it doesnot help.

I applied these code in `catalog.xml` class `catalog_product_view` in top,root and content but every time i see no result.

Answer (score 2):

Please add these codes below in your `app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/layout/catalog.xml` file:

```
   <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>                                                             
   <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review">
        <alias>product_additional_data</alias>
        <title>Reviews</title>
        <block>review/product_view_list</block>
        <template>review/product/view/list_tab.phtml</template>
   </action>
```

Comment: it not working!

Comment: can you try this in your theme as well as base folder??