# display Review tab in product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, review

**Is Displaying Reviews  tabs in product view page is default magento 1.9 feature ?**

if so,  it is hidden in our site. I want to display it again.

what code is reason to hide the `Review tab` in view page.

This question is not duplicate because i am not asking how to display reviews in product-view page, i want to display reviews as tabs in product view page as below image....

[image]

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen this is not `duplicate` , this question asked for adding `review as tab` , that question asked for  ` displaying review form`

Comment: also read the question once again....

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35129/add-review-form-to-product-page-magento-1-9 < here you can see exactly how to display the review form on your website. Or did you just want to know someone's opinion on this matter?

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen that is completely different question,  i wanted to display review as `tabs` , something like this :    http://prnt.sc/cnqtbi , also i wanted to know : `Is Displaying Reviews ab tabs in product view page is default magento 1.9 feature ?` , i repeat that is completely different question......

Comment: As you can see, it is magento default: http://magento-demo.lexiconn.com/accessories/jewelry/swing-time-earrings.html I'm not sure, what you expect as an answer, because we have no clue, how you removed it.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt thanks for your comment, but i wanted to tell that "this question is really not duplicate" , so if you change your decision & vote for `leave open` , that will be really justice for my knowledge, but if you don't do that also i still respect your decision& Thanks again for your precious time....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Review Form To Product Page Magento 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35129/add-review-form-to-product-page-magento-1-9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the *rwd* theme there is a reviews tab on the product page by default.

The most common ways to remove them would be

- "Disable Module Output" in *System > Configuration > Advanced*
- Layout XML update: `<remove name="product.reviews" />`
- Layout XML override (`review.xml` in your theme) where the `catalog_product_view` handle is removed

If none of these is the case, search your custom code for "review", there are countless "creative" ways to accomplish anything in Magento.

Answer (score 1):

IN RWD theme below code is responsible for adding review which is located in `review.xml` file by default

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" after="additional">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviews</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

You can see this code in review.xml file please check this kind of code in your theme's xml file and if it has no review tab then please check if your theme has `<remove name="product.reviews" />` this code some where in layout files.